# how can I update the content based on the images I click (Angular)

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I am new to the angular (precisely angular 9). I hope someone can guide me in the right direction.

I have 5 images placed vertically one below another on the left-hand side and in the middle, I have to update the content based on the image that I will click. In the middle, there could be any number of fields based on what image I will click. Can someone guide me on how can I do it?

Here is what I want: [Page design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJjtW.png)

Answer (score 0):

1. Create components for each button,
2. Add/Configure routes in app.module.ts
3. Add click event on buttons to navigate to those routes
4. Then load components with router-outlet

Answer (score 0):

for this, you must use the angular paths to load a component based on the image you click on, for example: put this attribute on the image routerLink = "/ customers",
where customers is the name of its component.
I leave you the link of the official documentation.

https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules

sorry my english is not very good.